# Issues with pxssh and idle3

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a strange issue with pxssh and idle3.

I've written a simple test program.

```
from tkinter import *

import pxssh

root = Tk();
root.title("Test");

def Test():
   try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login("[remote host]","[username]","[password]")
   except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print(e)

button = Button(root,text="Hello", command=Test, bg='green', width=20).place(x=20,y=40)

root.mainloop();
```

When I run this code from the command prompt (on a Raspberry Pi), it logins without a problem using both python2 and python3. (for Python2 I changed tkinter to Tkinter)

When I load this code in Idle, I can execute it, and it will login.

However, when I load this in Idle3, and execute it, I get a message similar to

```
could not set shell prompt
 unset PROMPT_COMMAND
error,09
$ PS1='[PEXPECT]\$ '

error,09
$ set prompt='[PEXPECT]\$ '
```

Is there something about Idle3 that does it?

Comment: It is more likely to be affected to the remote host you're connecting to - it assumes it will talk to a bash shell, but it looks like it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there anything about Idle3 that could cause the issue? As I mentioned, if I simply run the GUI with the command gksu python3 test.py, I can click the button, and it logs in. But running it in idle3, I get the error I mentioned

Comment: I don't think it could be affected by IDLE. But if you use `gksu`, it's running as the root user, which might make a difference.